# How do I store data in a json file?

Tags: javascript, json

For a class project we have to build an online store in 3 parts: html, css and js, the first 2 are done but i'm at a loss about js! We should be able to put the info of one product in a json file, and parse it in html. but tbh i'm not even sure how or where to begin with it, any suggestions are appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Also, please note that StackOverflow should not be used to just ask "please do my homework" to more experienced people. You should value the hard work that you will have to put into your studies. I strongly suggest you to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for replying, I didn't intend for it to sound like "someone come do my homework", I just wasn't even sure how to phrase it because I really didn't understand any of it, so sorry about that! And thanks for the resources!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First you can start by creating your JSON file that has all the information about the store that you want, then you can use JavaScript to read the data in that file. Finally you can use HTML and some binding to parse and show whatever you want. I can help you out if you post some sample code or a jsfiddle.

Comment: ah ok so i use javascript to read the data in the json file but the data itself should be in the json file, that had me very confused, thank you so much!! :D

Comment: Yes that is correct! I hope that clears things up. I know how hard it is sometimes to phrase a question when you don't really understand how some of the stuff work. Good luck! @Freckles